# Java url execution throws permission denied error

Tags: java, android, http, yahoo-api

The following code throws `permision denied expection`

```
String strurl = "https://login.yahoo.com/WSLogin/V1/get_auth_token?&login=name&passwd=passwd&oauth_consumer_key=dj0yJmk9WnhsVVZvSDhkYTVpJmQ9WVdrOWMwRlVZV0p2TkRnbWNHbzlNVFE0TURJek5qVTJNZy0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD0yNg";
URL url;
try
  {
    url = new URL(strurl);
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    System.out.println(urlConnection.getInputStream());
  }
catch (MalformedURLException e)
  {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
catch (IOException e)
  {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

If I use the URL directly in the browser I get a proper response in this case a request token is displayed.  What is the problem here; is there any other way if calling it?

Comment: you need to get permision to connect first since this is a secure url. how to get it, though, i dont know

Comment: how does it work in browser then ??

Comment: The same thing coy pasted in browser provides expected result

Comment: because you would be logged on and your browser would have permission to access that webpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not experienced with Android development but don't you have to define permissions in manifest xml to access network? (I suppose that you execute that code from Android by your tag)

Comment: Thank you , that was the issue .I don how that slipped my mind and i was thinking it was issue caused because  its a https .

Answer (score 1):

You need to add INTERNET permission to the AndroidManifest.xml, if you don't have it:

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` in your AndroidManifest.xml, just within the `Manifest` tags.